# Can I use my own custom authentication service in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I want to create chat application using Firebase. I have the backend done in micro-services.

I also built an authentication API micro-service that allow the user to login/register and other. That service is built in Node.js and Mongodb using JWT tokens.

I am not that familiar with Firebase, all I know that you can you their auth/authorization service.

Will it be alright to use that micro-service in Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Firebase Admin SDK to mint a token that Firebase Authentication can then use to authenticate your user.

See the [Firebase documentation on minting custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) for an example.